# How do I compare cells in two ranges and perform a calculation based on a match (Google Sheets)?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to compare two columns in two different sheets, and if there is a match, to perform a calculation using values that appear in sheet two.

Here's the scenario:

If a value in row 21 column K (sheet 1) matches a value anywhere in column B (sheet 2) then, I need to perform a calculation that includes a value from WITHIN the row (7 cells to the right) where the value in sheet 2, column B was found. If there is not a match found, then the cell should be left blank.

So...

1. Compare sheet 1, row 21, column K with sheet 2, column B for a matching value (there will only be one in sheet 2)
2. If match, perform a calculation that includes a value 7 columns (same row) to the right of the cell where the value was found in sheet 2, column B
3. If there is no match, the cell should be left blank.

This formula will be in row 21 column M of sheet 1.

I hope that makes sense. Very difficult to articulate, which is probably why I haven't found an answer after searching for quite a while now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that had you simplified the issue (as one is supposed to!) it may have been a little easier to describe, but you requirement seems to be little more than a simple lookup:

```
=iferror(vlookup(K21,Sheet2!B:I,8,0),"")*2
```

just with an error trap and something extra for the required formula (I chose just doubling - which will default to `0` not blank, but how best to handle that may depend upon the formula you have not provided).

Formula should allow copying up or down but, as it stands, not across.

Comment: Thanks again for this @pnuts. I noticed that my previous response was deleted. I am more than happy to learn how this site works. I am not on it very often, so that would explain my slow learning curve. Thanks for the tip on how to accept an answer. I went ahead and did that. Re: clarifying my question. As a beginner to Google Sheets, that remains difficult. That's why I'm here. Thanks for your help.